# Python converto datetime.isoformat(datetime.utcnow()) to mysql datetime format?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a python script that generates a datetime string using this line of code:

```
        data['timestamp'] = datetime.isoformat(datetime.utcnow())
```

That generates something like the following:

***2017-05-24T04:08:09.530033***

How do I convert that to "MYSQL insertable" datetime format in a clean way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use MySQL's STR_TO_DATE() function to parse the string that you're attempting to insert.

I hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

You can specify any type of format like this depending on the one you `ve set in mysql

```
data['timestamp'] =pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'] , format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: but I already have a lot of registers in that format in a text file that I need to convert to the other format, how I do this?

Comment: could you add in your question,how it is the file,how it is loaded in pandas,and which final format you it to converted to...

Answer (score 0):

First off, it looks like you ran `from datetime import *` rather than `import datetime`. That's tempting because it lets you type less when you want to refer to parts of the module, but it can get you into name collision issues later. An alternative with less typing is something like `import datetime as dt`, that way later you can just use dt.datetime. This will make your code cleaner.

MySQL accepts several date formats, which can be read about in detail [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). In particular:

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

ISO8601 numbers look just like that! `2017-05-24T04:19:32`

So if the only difference is the "T" in the middle instead of a space, just run something like this, assuming you don't change your import statements.

```
timestamp = str(datetime.isoformat(datetime.utcnow()))
timestamp = timestamp.replace("T", " ")
data['timestamp'] = timestamp
```